# adb.exe android gives me error with su

Tags: android, android-emulator

i rooted my device (lenovo 2107a) and then i update new custom firmware with bellow instructions:

```
download new firmware into sdcard/clockworkmod
boot to CWM
select "backup and restore" -> "advanced restore from internal sdcard"
and choose my custom ROM

then i select "system restore"
```

so i saw an error that said cannot restore and restore goes to break.
now when boot my device i see a screen that wants to select country code and after select device will reboot again and i see same screen.

so i decided to restore my old backup, but even old backup restoring gives me the error that cannot restore.

i find the problem, when i open shell with this command:

```
adb.exe shell
$su
su
segmentation fault
```

the problem is that all of data in /system is read-only and i cannot even root with su. i tried everything like re-rooting device, but still i cannot shell as root.

mount cannot be run (operation not permitted)

adb.exe remount (cannot be execute)

fixsu.sh cannot be execute because has not access to /system (everything is read-only)

psneuter gives (failed to set prot mask (inappropriate ioctl for device))

is there any way to delete /system and re-upload that or something that can solve my problem?

Comment: maybe http://android.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question. However I'd try to `adb shell` into the device with clockworkmod booted, you should be able to mount/wipe from there. Or just re-flash your rom or the superuser app from there.

Comment: thank you for your comment, would you please explain that how can i re-flash my rom?

Comment: Search for [android clockworkmod flash zip](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+clockworkmod+flash+zip), if you used a stock rom, you can usually find them on [xda-developers](http://www.xda-developers.com/).